# Python - URLretrieve giving 401 error while trying to download a file

Tags: python

When I try to download a file from a URL using urlretrieve, I get an unauthorized error.  It ultimately translates to  "You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied because your Web browser is sending a WWW-Authenticate header field that the Web server is not configured to accept."
The site uses NTLM authentication and I am able to open the site using the same credentials.  It fails when I try to download a file. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try [Python-NTLM](http://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/)?

Comment: Thank you Seth.. I did try Python NTLM. I am able to open the URL using NTLM authentication.  However, I get an unauthorized error when I try to download files using urlretrieve.  My requirement is to download files from the URL and I face this issue. Please let me know if I am missing anything here...